# If $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)>0$ whenever $f(x)<0$, must $f$ be non-negative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be a smooth function. If $f(0)=0$ and
>   for $x\in(0,\infty)$ we know $f'(x)>0$ whenever $f(x)<0$, can we
>   conclude that $f$ is non-negative on $[0,\infty)$?

I think this is obviously true, but is there a rigorous way to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can. Hint: mean value theorem.